# Программа "Не видит" dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

Приложение, написанное на C# и dll на C++/CLI. dll-ка подключена к проекту на C# через references.  В коде вызываются методы классов объявленных в dll'ке.
На моём компе всё работает. На компе коллег так же (у всех примерно одинаковый конфиг: x64 Core i3-i5 Win8.1-10) А на удалённой машине (Atom 1.5 Win7 sp1 x86) пишет

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WinPrint.dll" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не найден указанный модуль

Файл dll лежит в папке с exeшником. В свойствах проекта для данной dll стоит "копировать локально". Все проекты компилируются под x86. VisualStudio 2015

Причём что, запускаю на своём компе regsvr32 и регаю dll-видит, но говорит что неверный формат (что корректно) а на удалённой машине пишет

> Не найден указанный модуль

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможные причины:

1) Разная разрядность `ОС` и конфигурация билда.

2) Зависимости `.dll`, у меня было нечто подобное, отсутствовала зависимость, но `p\invoke .NET-а` долбал сообщение об ошибке что не видит подключаемую `.dll`, а не ее зависимость. Советую на удаленном ПК проверить зависимости нативной `.dll` утилитой `Dependency Walker`.

Comment: regsvr32 не видит dll От слова совсем... Если была б неверной разрядности или не хватало бы зависимости какой он бы соответствующим образом ругнулся или бы просто сказал что неформат. А он пишет что нет её, хотя она вот ровно по тому пути который я ему передаю

Comment: @Alexey, Вы должны понимать что магии не бывает. В моем случае regsvr32 молчал.

Comment: @Alexey, добавлю еще - перечитайте свой вопрос, цитирую: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WinPrint.dll" либо `одну из их зависимостей`. Не найден указанный модуль"

Comment: Создал тестовую dll у которой один метод возвращающий false. Зависимостей 0. На целевой компьютер установил C++ 2015 Redistributable(x86) и... ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Alexey, после установки VC++ - целевой ПК ребутили?

Comment: да, ребутил. Также актуализировал версию .Net. без изменений.

Comment: Dependency Walker пробовали? Я не знаток C++, но разные версии VC++ либ сделали не просто так. Может в 2015 версии просто нету того, что нужно?

Comment: Таки да, зря я сразу не послушал совета про Dependency Walker... Даже пустой проект тянет за собой зависимость в виде VCRUNTIME140D.dll которая есть только на компах с установленной студией.... В принципе проблема локализована. Теперь нужно решить как от неё избавиться...